# Trying To Get Three Rectangles Drawn In Canvas To Grow Vertically When Mouse Is Clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to get three rectangles printed in HTML5's Canvas tags to grow vertically each time I click the canvas with my mouse.

So far my code draws the three squares.  I have a growBy function, but when I click, nothing moves.  Would the forum take a look at my code and tell me where I went wrong?

Thanks,

Michael

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
 <body>
   <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400">
   <h3>Your Browser Does Not Support This Page.  Please Update To Latest Version.</h3>
   </canvas>
   <script type="application/javascript" src="script.js">
   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
canvas  { 
border: 1px solid black; 
}
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
// JavaScript For Canvas 
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var Square = function (x, y, width, height) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
};

Square.prototype.growBy = function(amount) {
        this.height += amount;
        console.log("growing!");    
};

var DrawSquare = function (x, y, width, height) {
            Square.call(this, x, y, width, height);
};

DrawSquare.prototype = Object.create(Square.prototype);

DrawSquare.prototype.draw = function (color) {
            ctx.clearRect(this.x,this.y,this.width,this.height);
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect (this.x, this.y, this.width,this.height);
};

var squareOne = new DrawSquare(0,375,25,25);
var squareTwo = new DrawSquare(40, 375, 25, 25);
var squareThree = new DrawSquare(80,375,25, 25);




var drawScene = function() {
    squareOne.draw("rgb(243, 83, 23)");
    squareTwo.draw("rgb(163, 187, 81)");
    squareThree.draw("rgb(38, 154, 214)");

};

document.getElementById("canvas").onclick = function() {
    console.log("hello!");
    squareOne.growBy(10);
    drawScene();
};

drawScene();
```

All help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/d3jht0bp/1/

```
Square.prototype.growBy = function(amount) {
    this.y -+ amount;
    this.height += amount;
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillRect (this.x, this.y-amount, 
        this.width,this.height+amount);
};
```

You can see that all I'm doing is drawing another rectangle on top of the existing rectangle. I made `color` a property of the object so I can access it here.

`canvas` is a bitmap; we can only draw and erase it-- there are no nodes or objects stored to it. I recommend [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/) if you want an easier way to create canvas-like objects and manipulate them. But if you want to stick with `canvas` and learn more about making it dynamic, checkout [Simon Sarris' tutorial](http://simonsarris.com/blog/510-making-html5-canvas-useful). He uses an interval timer to refresh the canvas every 30ms; on that refresh, the state of the canvas is validated, which means the app logic runs and redraws itself every 30ms.